# How to make different border colors in div box?

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

working with Laravel and I have display some div box background color according to adtype values of the table. currently using following background colors according to adtype values,

```
<div style="border-style: solid; background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? '#FFEFD5' : '#FFFFFF' }} ">
```

but now I need paste different color to border like if adtype===1 red and adtype===0 green. I have only 2 adtype values like 1 and 0. how can I do this?

Comment: You can set the CSS property "border-color" just like you're setting the background-color in your template there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the CSS property "[border-color](http://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/border-color)" just like you're setting the background-color in your template there.

```
<div style="border-style: solid; border-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'red' : 'green' }}; 
     background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? '#FFEFD5' : '#FFFFFF' }} ">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
<?php
$adtype = $vehicule->adtype
switch((int) $adtype)
{
  case 1: 
     $bgcolor = "red";
     $bordercolor = "somecolor";
     break;

  case 2:
     $bgcolor = "green";
     $bordercolor = "someothercolor";
     break;


  default: 
     $bgcolor = "#ffffff";
     $bordercolor = "#defaultcolor";

}
?>
<div style="border-style: solid; background-color: <?php echo $bgcolor; ?>; border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:<?php echo $bordercoler; ?>;">
```

Comment: may I use boarder color in like background color ?

Comment: @Jamie_D Why would switching to PHP work better than doing this in Blade?

Comment: @YetiCGN  Downvoted? Really? Last time I checked Laravel 5 was a PHP framework not to mention using `switch` gives the option of different background and border colors for each criteria ...

Comment: That's like saying "hey, why don't you solve your problem with JavaScript?" just because JS is used in the project as well. Before your edit there was no mention of a border-color and that's when I downvoted and commented. Even after your edit your code doesn't work, because it uses an undefined variable `$bordercoler`. I stand by my downvote.

Comment: OK then. The boss just added three more ad types. Give us your Blade solution and we'll all be happy.